# Zapier cannot find module when testing the action

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, zapier

So I created a Zapier app with an action using the node package mongoose to update a document in a remote db. When I test it locally with Zapier test, it manages to complete the update, but when I test it on zapier.com for a zap, I get the error `Cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection'`

[Clippings from zapier.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rn4r.png)

Comment: That's very strange! I too was able to run it locally but it didn't work on lambda, which makes me think the issue is an AWS one. I would double check with mongoose that everything plays nicely when mongoose and all its deps are zipped and sent to AWS lambda to be run all together. I'm sorry I don't know more info!

Comment: I can even successfully update using npm runkit online.

Comment: Got it working with mongodb, not mongoose though.

Comment: intersting. did you change anything major?

Comment: Meant got it working with the npm module mongodb, didn't end up using mongoose.